# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Add Metrics to compile function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using a Convolutional neural Network and after I start running it I get the error stated in my question:

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/CNN1_FOLD1.py", line 452, in 
> main_dense(0.1, DenseNet, error_anal = True, depth=depth)
>
> File "/home/CNN1_FOLD1.py", line 440, in main_dense
> train(model, x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, epochs_list = [500, 5000, 300], name = model_name, learning_rate = learning_rate)
>
> File "/home/CNN1_FOLD1.py", line 320, in train
> 'AUC'])
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
> line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 222, in compile
> masks=masks)
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 871, in _handle_metrics
> self._per_output_metrics[i], target, output, output_mask)
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 842, in _handle_per_output_metrics
> metric_fn, y_true, y_pred, weights=weights, mask=mask)
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py",
> line 1033, in call_metric_function
> update_ops = metric_fn.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=weights)
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py",
> line 42, in decorated
> update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/metrics.py",
> line 318, in update_state
> matches = self._fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/metrics.py",
> line 1421, in **init**
> thresholds, default_threshold=default_threshold)
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py",
> line 107, in parse_init_thresholds
> assert_thresholds_range(to_list(thresholds))
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py",
> line 98, in assert_thresholds_range
> invalid_thresholds = [t for t in thresholds if t is None or t < 0 or t > 1]
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py",
> line 98, in 
> invalid_thresholds = [t for t in thresholds if t is None or t < 0 or t > 1]
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 765, in **bool**
> self._disallow_bool_casting()
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 534, in _disallow_bool_casting
> self._disallow_in_graph_mode("using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
>
> File
> "/home/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 523, in _disallow_in_graph_mode
> " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))
>
> OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`
> is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate
> this function with @tf.function.

I understand it is related to my metrics. I was initially running it as shown below:

```
   model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer=opt, 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But I wanted to add some more metrics, so I changed it to:

```
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer=opt, 
                  metrics=['accuracy',
                           'Precision',
                           'Recall',
                           'AUC'])
```

Or:

```
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer=opt, 
                  metrics=['accuracy',
                           tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                           tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
                           'AUC'])
```

Both did not work and gave me the error.

What could I do to solve the issue?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a similar problem. Since TensorFlow upgraded to 2.x, to use keras API metrics you should instantiate all of them in order to compile like so:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer=opt, 
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy(),
                           tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                           tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
                           tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To give some context on how I got this error, I was trying to convert darknet weights to a TensorFlow model, following [this](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort) tutorial.
I got this error due to the following piece of code:

```
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters_shape[-1], kernel_size = filters_shape[0], strides=strides, padding=padding,
                              use_bias=not bn, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0005),
                              kernel_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
                              bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.))(input_layer)

if bn: conv = BatchNormalization(dynamic=True)(conv)        ### added dynamic=True
```

Once I added the argument `dynamic=True` I was able to resolve this issue.